# Error: Invalid hex string

Tags: node.js

Here is my node js code

```
if (protocol == '01') {
  console.log('...goint to get Ack Obj...');
  var o = getAckObj(hexString);
  console.log('...ack obj received...');
  var msg = ackMsg(o);
  console.log('..going to write buffer...');
  socket.write(new Buffer(msg, 'hex')); //, 'binary');
  console.log('Server sent welcome: ' + msg);
}

.....

function ackMsg(dataObj) {
  var ackText = '';
  dataObj.len = '05'; //for ack msg its always 05
  var e = crc16(dataObj.len + dataObj.protocol + dataObj.serial, 'hex');
  dataObj.error = e.toString(16);
  return dataObj.start + dataObj.len + dataObj.protocol + dataObj.serial + dataObj.error + dataObj.stop;
}
```

Here is the value in hexString `78780d010387113120864842000ccbe40d0a`

On console out put

```
...goint to get Ack Obj...
...ack obj received...
..going to write buffer...
buffer.js:348
      ret = this.parent.hexWrite(string, this.offset + offset, length);
```

Comment: `new Buffer()` takes as second argument the encoding of the message. By encoding it refers to character encoding (defaults to `utf8`) and not numerical encoding.

Comment: @ThalisK. `hex` is a valid encoding to use with `Buffer` (`base64` is another one). @coure2011 given that `dataObj.len` is `05`, and the value you're showing doesn't contain that, are you sure `msg` is correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct... this len is not showing length of the whole message but its purpose is something different.

Comment: @coure2011 and `msg.length` is an even number, right?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the length of your string is even? Buffer raises that (unclear) error message when the hex string you're providing is odd (`len % 2 != 0`) rather than the required even.

A good test would be to log the hex string you have, and then try it in Python:

```
>>> '8'.decode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Odd-length string
```

I've opened a pull-request on GitHub to fix the error message to be a bit more clear: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4877/files

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped into this issue too nowadays with an old io.js, the node version was 1.2.

Here is a code sample where I got such error as you:

```
const resultBuffer = new Buffer.concat(chunks.items);
fs.writeFileSync(resultFilePath, resultBuffer, {encoding: 'hex'});
```

I checked double times the `chunks.items` and then used simple hex oddless value as @JJ Geewax mentioned and found that the problem in my case was in interaction between node fs module and Buffer.

To get it working I've changed from passing a raw Buffer into string with right encoding:

```
...
fs.writeFileSync(resultFilePath, resultBuffer.toString('hex'), {encoding: 'hex'});
```

Maybe someone found this useful.